# How to replace substrings with strings from array using preg_replace? (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, string, preg-replace

I have a data array containing these values:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [myid] => 9
    [date] => 2014-01-30
    [user] => 17
    [reason] => some text here...
)
```

And this string which contains numbers referring to the data array indexes:

```
$columns = '(0) as "id",(1) as "myid",(2) as "date",(3) as "user",(4) as "reason"';
```

Is it possible to change the numbers enclosed in brackets, including brackets to appropriate value from the array?

I know how to work with `(string) preg_replace( (array)  $patterns, (array) $replacements, (string) $subject)` but quite don't know how to solve this problem.

Ideally the result string could look like this:

```
'1' as "id",'9'  as "myid",'2014-01-30'  as "date",'17'  as "user",'some text here...'  as "reason"
```

Comment: Have a look at [array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) or [array_reduce()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) to build a single string.

Comment: Why do you want that result? What is it for?

Comment: Why you need to change the string, why not new string from array?

Comment: Quasimodo's clone: For Sqlite query @Frayne Konok: I could do it so, this would be the simplest way.

Comment: @JohnBoe, But why you want to make it complex??

Comment: @Frayne Konok: I will listen to you, I will do it as you suggested

Comment: After your edits it turns out, that a simple preg_replace_callback fits your needs best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution using `preg_replace_callback` and `str_replace` functions:

```
$columns = '(0) as "id",(1) as "myid",(2) as "date",(3) as "user",(4) as "reason"';

// $arr is your initial array
$result = preg_replace_callback(
                "/(\(\d\)) as \"(\w+?)\",?/i",
                function ($maches) use($arr){
                     return str_replace([$maches[1]], "'". $arr[$maches[2]]. "'", $maches[0]);
                },
                $columns);

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
'1' as "id",'9' as "myid",'2014-01-30' as "date",'17' as "user",'some text here...' as "reason"
```

Comment: Thank you. I accept your question because I think this is best answer. Nevertheless the Frayne's suggestion in comments is my current solution.

Comment: yes, the Frayne's suggestion would be quite reasonable if you are dealing with a real code(production). But I've presented the solution as a solution for your current "abstract" test case. Anyway, thanks

Comment: That's great, I also make an answer using some PHP library functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a simple `foreach` loop:

```
$info = array(
    'id' => 1,
    'myid' => 9,
    'date' => '2014-01-30',
    'user' => 17,
    'reason' => 'some text here...'
);

$columns = '(0) as "id",(1) as "myid",(2) as "date",(3) as "user",(4) as "reason"';

foreach (array_values($info) as $key => $value) {
    $columns = str_replace(
        '(' . $key . ')',
        str_pad($value, strlen($value) + 2, "'", STR_PAD_BOTH),
        $columns
    );
}

echo $columns;
```

Comment: What if the string starts with `$columns = '(0) as "myid",(1) as "id",` ?

Comment: ha ha ha, There is a lot of questions, But the OP's requirement is resolved .

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using just some PHP library functions.

```
$info = array(
    'id' => 1,
    'myid' => 9,
    'date' => '2014-01-30',
    'user' => 17,
    'reason' => 'some text here...'
);

$columns = '(0) as "id",(1) as "myid",(2) as "date",(3) as "user",(4) as "reason"';

$new_Arr = array();
$column_arr = explode(",", $columns);
foreach($column_arr as $values){
    $arr = explode(" as ", $values);
    $new_Arr[] = "'".$info[trim($arr[1], '"')]."' as ".$arr[1];
}

echo implode(",", $new_Arr) //'1' as "id",'9' as "myid",'2014-01-30' as "date",'17' as "user",'some text here...' as "reason"
```

Comment: complex way but you get it. +1

Comment: @RaviHirani, Actually one person did it using `str_pad` and `str_replace`, Another person `preg_replace_callback`, So the left is `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a loop with str_replace. Iterate through array, use loop index in brackets as a search string and replace it with corrsponding value.

Answer (score 0):

> [array_flip](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) is your saviour

Straight from docs

```
<?php
$input = array("oranges", "apples", "pears");
$flipped = array_flip($input);

print_r($flipped);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [oranges] => 0
    [apples] => 1
    [pears] => 2
)
```